# What is a proper way to keep user settings synchronized with the server?

Tags: java, android, rest, sharedpreferences

I can't think of a proper method to do this and I had no luck searching on the internet.

In a RESTful API I want to let the user change the settings. It would be easy with a PreferenceFragment (or the equivalent Activity) saving the data in the SharedPreferences but how can I keep that data synchronized with the server? e.g. Change the user name, change the alias, the notifications settings. That data must be in the server.

Is there a clean and easy way to do this, maybe adapting PreferenceFragment or perhaps some library?

Comment: Why don't you just let users update their accounts my making a POST request to the server and update a local table in the device respectively?

Comment: But how do such POST request and update in a clean way? Similar to PreferenceFragment where you can just feed it an xml with the settings and it builds it easily.
My question is about what is the proper way to do it

Comment: Your question is kind of vague.  What do you mean by "in a clean way"?  Is your API returning JSON?  You can use org.json or GSON to parse it, pull out values, and put them into SharedPreferences.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is how can I use PreferenceFragment and update any change in the server side, not how to send the request itself to the server but rather how to trigger such request when a user changes a value. Or any similar solution not necessarily involving PreferenceFragment.

Comment: Just do a request when a user hits SAVE or UPDATE button.